# Haven't got 100 Unicoins on Stack Overflow yet

Tags: support, unicoins

On Stack Overflow, I purchased `Guaranteed Answer` power and then I wanted to get `tag adoption`, but I didn't have enough Unicoins. So, I paid in full $9.99 using PayPal. Why haven't I got my 100 Unicoins yet?

Comment: For all of the downvoters, look at your calendars.

Comment: @SecondRikudo Just because we know it's a joke doesn't mean we think it's funny.

Comment: Could not replicate. Currently March 31st EDT. Prefer Narwoins in any case.

Comment: Will? Izzat you?

Comment: Today is 1st Apr ... Stackoverflow  sounds like Google

Comment: Let us all engage in some silly-games, the calendar doth alloweth us

Comment: Still can not replicate. Currently April 1st EDT. Spent all my coins on bobbleheads instead. Narwoins still better.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Please allow six to eight weeks for shipping. Unicoins are a delicate material and require extra care when sending them. We're looking at ways of shipping them digitally instead of via carrier pidgeons, but I'm afraid the technology isn't quite there yet.

Comment: I, for one, am proud to work for a company where [RFC 1149](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1149.txt) is supported.

Answer (score 15):

Ask the NSA.  I suspect they are skimming Unicoins to fund their datacenters, and accidentally set the skimming parameter to 100%.